# next_post_link for CPT only working for a few posts? weird!

Tags: pagination, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I have about 20-30 posts in a CPT, and when I click on a single post and use the next_post_link and prev_post_link functions it will only show a select 5 posts out of the 20-30... always the same 5 as well.. I can't for the life of me work out why!

I've tried limiting to taxonomies or categories but that just brings it down to 0 links.

Has anyone come across this?

EDIT: I'm using a very streamlined install... the only plugins are CPT UI for the Custom Post Type and ACF for the fields.

Here is my code for the single-books.php (Single CPT page) the url is site.com/books/book-name

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main role="main">
    <section>

    <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <div class="col3">
                <h1 class="title"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col3">
                <div class="cover">
                    <?php $cover = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_field('cover_image'), 'book' ); ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $cover[0]; ?>" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col3">

            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="col3">
                <span class="label">Author:</span>
                <span class="data"><?php the_field('author') ?></span>
                <span class="label">Publisher:</span>
                <span class="data"><?php the_field('publisher') ?></span>
                <span class="share">[ Share ]</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col3">
                <span class="label">Review</span>
                <span class="data"><?php the_content(); ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="col3">
                <span class="label">Publication Date:</span>
                <span class="data"><?php the_field('publication_date') ?></span>
                <span class="label">Genre:</span>
                <span class="data"><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'genres', '', ', ', '' ) ?></span>
                <span class="label">Reviewer:</span>
                <span class="data"><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'staff', '', ', ', '' ) ?></span>
                <?php if (get_field('buy_link')) : ?><span class="buy"><a target="_blank" href="<?php the_field('buy_link') ?>">· Buy Now ·</a></span><?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="col3 align-right pagination">
                <?php previous_post_link( '%link', '&laquo Previous Book', FALSE ); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col3">
                <hr>
            </div>

            <div class="col3 align-left pagination">
                <?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next Book &raquo', FALSE ); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="spacer"></div>

        </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using? Impossible to figure what can be happening without seeing some code.

Comment: There must be something in your theme or is a plugin causing this. This is not a failure of the function itself. Your problem is just too localized for anyone to help you. The only advice I can give is, turn debugging on, disble plugins and swirch to a bundled theme. If none of this work, back up your sire and reinstall wordpress. Also look out for custom queries on your single page that could affect this. Good luck

Comment: @cybmeta - I've posted my code.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `FALSE` at the end and just have `next_post_link( '%link', 'Next Book &raquo' )` ?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Originally didn't have that so tried adding it and it didn't help. Thanks though.

Comment: And it's safe to assume the files code you added was in some kind of archive or taxonomy template? `archive-post-type-slug.php` or `taxonomy.php`? Could you edit your question and list the plugins you have installed? Have you tried Pieter Goosens suggestion?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I've updated the question, the code is on the single php file for the CPT

Comment: do the posts that are skipped happen to have identical publish dates/times?

Comment: @Milo - Yes potentially.. they were all imported at the same time using an import script. Could that be it?

Comment: both of those functions use [`get_adjacent_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post) which selects posts by date that are either greater or less than the date of the current post, so it seems it would skip posts that have dates identical to the current post.

Comment: @Milo WOW that was it! well done - nice work! That's an interesting bug but it makes sense! Import plugins such as WP All Import should have a feature / fix for that.

Answer (score 1):

@Milo solved this one - It was because the posts were imported using an import plugin hence having all the same date bar a few that ticked over every second! All posts must have a unique date / time in order for next and prev links to work.